# Analytics API : automatic authentification

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to build a dashboard using Google Analytics Reporting API, in order to create reports for my company's clients.

The problem is that I need to create reports using a cronjob, but this requires an authentication. I tried the following approaches :

**1. Using the [API for web applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php) :**

I managed to make this work, but the OAuth2 process forces me to authenticate into Google by redirecting me to the Google login page. Once logged in, the token is created and my report is generated. But I couldn't find a way to authenticate automatically without a user intervention (i.e. filling the Google login form)

**2. Using the [API for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) :**

With this solution, I am able to create reports without manually logging into Google, which is awesome. But this method requires me to add the service account to the Google Analytics account, by adding the newly created user `XXXXXXXX@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com` to each of the Google Analytics view I wish to access. I can't do that, as some of the views I'm trying to access are managed by my company's clients and I can't ask each of them to add yet another Analytics user.

I need to be able to access the Analytics views using the user e-mail already configured. I tried to add this address as the owner of my service account in the [Service Accounts Manager](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts), but no luck (see screenshots hereafter).

[image: Service Accounts Manager]

[image: Analytics Administration]

Is there any way I can either use the API for web applications with a static token (i.e. without having to manually log into Google), or use the API for service accounts without having to add the Google-created user in each of my Analytics views ?

I'm at a loss here, so any advice will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the fact that you don't have control of all of the accounts as you said you wont be able to use a service account.

There for you will have to use Oauth2.  Someone will have to authenticate your application the first time.  Once access has been granted the first time you will be given an access token to access the API and a refresh token.   If you store this refresh token you will then be able to request a new access token from your cron job when ever you like in order to run your reports.

The trick is saving the refresh token associated with each users account.  Your clients will have to authenticate the application to grant you access. You store the refresh token.  The refresh token shouldn't expire (there are a few reasons why one might) you will be able to gain access when ever needed.

Note: You can also place the service account email at the account level will give you access to everything.   But this wont help you with clients you don't have access to.

**Update:**

Refresh tokens will not expire except under:

- A refresh token not used for 6 months will also expire.
- users can go to App settings on there google account and revoke your access at anytime.

A user can re-authenticate your application (same client id) 26 times giving you 26 different refresh tokens, after number 26 the first refresh token will expire. You can only have 26 working refresh tokens for a single user.  Make sure you always save the newest refresh token.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks. I have one question though, is the refresh token specific to each Analytics property (i.e. if I want to retrieve the stats for 20 different sites, I'll have to create 20 refresh tokens) even if those properties are all managed in the same Analyitics account (by "account", I mean the email and password I use to authorize the API using OAuth2) ?

Comment: Refresh token gives you access to all of the Google Analytics accounts the authenticated user has access to

Comment: Awesome ! I'll try that in the next few days and let you know how it went !

Comment: Tried it, it works like a charm, I can't believe how easy it was and how long it took for me to find this out. Thank you so much. BTW, could you tell me what would be the reasons why a refresh token might expire ?

Comment: see if that makes sence

Comment: Yup, that makes sense. Since my cron will be launched every day and no one is supposed to have access to the Google Account, I guess I should'nt be worried. Thanks for your help, if I could upvote you 100 times, I would ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the intended method for cron jobs is to use API for service accounts, just as you have described. However, it seems to be an expected and appropriate behavior, that you cannot access a random view just by providing its ID with your service account, without prior authorization from the owner of the view. Without this settings, Analytics will not know about your relationship to your client, and therefore refuse access to data.

I'm not sure, if it is supported, but you could try to add your service account on property or Analytics account level, so that all connected views inherit this setting.

Comment: Same problem, I have over 200 Analytics accounts and I can't add a user for each of them (mainly because I only have reading permissions on some of them).